# Issue upgrading spring plugin in grails

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, grails-domain-class, spring-ldap

I am upgrading my application, i was using:

```
compile ":spring-security-core:1.2.7"
compile ":spring-security-ldap:1.0.6"
```

and upgraded it to

```
compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC5"
compile ":spring-security-ldap:2.0-RC2"
```

After making changes related to the packages, i am not able to see the login page. It keep me redirecting to **/login/auth**.
What more needs to be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your login page requires no authentication - use either [static rule/annotation](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/single.html#configGroovyMap) or enable access to all pages by default in the config.groovy:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rejectIfNoRule = false
```